# Changing data to be used in Pivot table from columns to row

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have an excel file which data in the following format. For example, the data consists of Name, Email and courses information which shows if they are "Passed", "In-Progress" or "Not Enrolled" or "Not-started"

[Link to image here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TwyiTYBgu5QhUL1Pn46Svxbv5jUMCiYA/view?usp=sharing)

I want to create a Pivot Table from this data and display some information such as how many courses are there and how many users are there in total.

Or preferably convert the data in the following format on which I can apply pivot tables easily such as this: [Link to Image 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TYAdDQ6VMrNBoUmGvcOZBMZ5Hcux17uo/view?usp=sharing)

I want to obtain the following through pivot table: [Image 3](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10PVO-CKcZ6VEyFcN9YnZ_Ic1TdfKiQ1U/view?usp=sharing)

Any help on this would be really appreciated. This is a sample data, the original data has 1000s of rows and 100s of column so doing it manually will not be possible.

Regards - M

Comment: Use power query a.k.a. Get and Transform, and unpivot the Course columns.